# Rebalance tasks in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

I have a moderation table that stores which post is assigned to which moderator. I want to periodically rebalance this table. Rebalancing means that all available moderators should have roughly equal number of unmoderated posts assigned to them. Moderation table has following format.

```
+---------+------------+--------------+
| mod_id  | post_id    | is_moderated |
+---------+------------+--------------+
```

I am fairly new to postgresql. I am using it with django python. What is the best way to do this?

There are a set of mod_id values that should have roughly equal number of post_id assigned to them when is_moderatoed is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it in `Database level`, you can use `Postgresql Trigger`. There django implemented library - [Django PgTrigger](https://django-pgtrigger.readthedocs.io).

> And there method for what you want. [Keeping a field in-sync with
> another](https://django-pgtrigger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#keeping-a-field-in-sync-with-another)

Or in `Django level` you can do with with [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/).